# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=2.3.0.0 in VSIX project

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Version Used: 2.3.2

Steps to Reproduce:

Create a VSIX (c#) project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with .Net framework 4.6
Add latest Microsoft.CodeAnalysis library to VSIX project
Add menu command to the VSIX project
Add following code in menu command action

```
string projectFilePath = @"C:\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj";
string outputFilePath = @"C:\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.dll";
Project project = null;

    using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
    {
        project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectFilePath).Result;
        var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        var compilationStatus = compilation.Emit(outputFilePath);
        bool isSuccess = compilationStatus.Success; 
    }
```

Expected Behavior:
Roslyn should be able to compile the project and emit output to target location.

Actual Behavior:
Following exception occurred when invoking the command.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Note:
Error doesn't occur and command executes successfully when version of the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is downgraded to 1.3.2

Please let me know if any fix is available for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [What's the latest version of Roslyn my analyzer can target if I support VS2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678861/whats-the-latest-version-of-roslyn-my-analyzer-can-target-if-i-support-vs2015/45680699#45680699).  Roslyn 1.3.2 is the newest version that will work with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Marlof, As per your post, Roslyn is not backward compatible, which means my extension will not work in VS 2015 Update 3 if I upgrade to latest. Do you know any solution to make it compatible with both VS 2015 Update 3 and VS 2017 Update 3 ?

Comment: If you reference version 1.3.2 your extension will work on both.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon, I have downgraded to 1.0.0, now it works in 2015 Update 3 and 2017 Update 3, hoping it will work in all the versions greater than Visual Studio 2015.0 (RTM)