# How do Roslyn versions map to Visual Studio versions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn

There is a very useful comment on github: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10514#issuecomment-242311407

Is there an official source for such mapping that covers all the released version?

Answer (score 1):

I added a more recent mapping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678861/whats-the-latest-version-of-roslyn-my-analyzer-can-target-if-i-support-vs2015/45680699#45680699) but there is nothing on the roslyn wiki yet.  Sounds like a good idea to add it.